# Using webform module without storing the submissions

Tags: webforms

On the youtube tutorial [Emailing & handling submissions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMCqqBJfWnk&ab_channel=JacobRockowitz) from [jrockowitz](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/972/jrockowitz), the main maintainer of the webform module, he said at [7:13](https://youtu.be/oMCqqBJfWnk?t=433) that webform can be used without storing the submissions.
For GPDR concerns, I would need to use the form only to send an email with the datas to an external service

How can I set that ?

Comment: Isn’t that just a checkbox under the settings somewhere for each webform?

Comment: @clive genial.It is indeed in the general tab. could not find it with all that many options

Comment: @clive there is a problem though, the uploaded files are stored !?

Comment: The files would then be deleted automatically by garbage collection on cron runs, did you check that?

Comment: they are indeed deleted after 6h. If submissions are configured not to be stored , i would expect the uploaded files not being stored either. It is a problem in my use case where i have made the uploaded files public so they can be accessible by a external service. I would need to suprress them straight after an email has been sent